# Install Carthage fail on Apple M2 Sonoma

Tags: ios, xcode, rosetta, apple-m2

brew install carthage command give below error, Please help me

Cannot install under Rosetta 2 in ARM default prefix (/opt/homebrew)!
To rerun under ARM use:
arch -arm64 brew install ...
To install under x86_64, install Homebrew into /usr/local.

Comment: I have fixed the same with series of command. Hope it may help anyone of you. 
brew install carthage
arch -arm64 brew upgrade 
cd /opt 
 sudo mkdir homebrew   
sudo chown $(whoami):admin homebrew
 curl -L https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/tarball/master | tar xz --strip 1 -C homebrew
 cd
Cd root folder
brew install carthage
carthage update --use-xcframeworks
carthage update --platform iOS --use-xcframeworks